# How would you characterise the difference between the grammatical structure of these two sentences?

Tags: grammar

How would you characterise the difference between the grammatical structure of these two sentences?

- in a weird way, you were fun
- you were fun in a weird way

The latter seems to be modifying 'fun' while the former is a parenthetical modifier of the independent clause, right, the complete thought "you were fun" (which may carry a different connotation - if e.g. you mean to ironize the word 'fun' then there is less a sense that inversion itself is "weird")?

If that's nonsense, then what isn't?

Comment: Yes. In the latter, the nature of the fun you provided was weird.  In the former, it's as if the predication itself is being qualified, rather like a concession of some kind.

Comment: yeah that makes sense @TimR thanks

Comment: In both cases "in a weird way" is a **manner adjunct** in clause structure. In the first, the adjunct is preposed, where it serves as a supplement, a non-dependent item. In the second, it is in its basic post-verbal position, serving as a modifier in the copula VP "were fun in a weird way". Note that "fun in a weird way" is not a constituent. Same meaning in both.